# return Null Fetch Javascript API

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

When creating a data with Fetch by javascript, they come as Null when displayed on the screen, but by Postman it is done as normal. You can help? The ID is also shown normally in the html, but author and txt are not

```ts
export const listPhrases = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let list = await Phrase.findAll({})
    res.json({list})
}
```

```ts
export const createPhrase = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  let { author, txt} = req.body;
  let newPhrase = await Phrase.create({ author, txt });
  res.status(201);
  res.json({ id: newPhrase.id, author, txt });
}
```

```ts
 async function getPhrases () {
             const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/frases')
             const data = await response.json()
             const phrase = await (data.list)

             let newPhrases = '';
                phrase.forEach(((item) => {
                    let newPhrasesPost = `
                    <h5>${item.txt}</h5>`
                    newPhrases += newPhrasesPost
                }))
                document.getElementById("phrase").innerHTML = newPhrases;
}
```

```js
async function newPhrase() {
  let inputPhrase = document.getElementById("inputPhrase").value;
  let author = document.getElementById("author").value;

  let phrasePost = { inputPhrase, author };

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(phrasePost)
  };

  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/frases", options);
  getPhrases();
}
```

Comment: Why are you not doing anything with `response`? And what is `getPhrases`?

Comment: Is it `/phrases` or really `/frases`?

Comment: "*they come as Null when displayed on the screen*" - you didn't show any code that displays something on the screen, so we can't tell you why

Comment: If I had to guess, your Postman request is using `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters and not JSON. To handle JSON you'd need the appropriate middleware, eg `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: @Bergi 
it returns the sentences in my html, they are displayed normally, but when I insert via input, they arrive as nul

Comment: @JoãoPedroJardim So what debugging have you done? Where do your variables still contain the expected text, and where do they start containing `null`?

Comment: I added app.use(express.json()) and it worked, thanks guys